# How to remove filter with script but only if one exists?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

The opening part of my script is to remove the filters on two datasets on two different tabs. The simple script below works for me but only if there is a filter already set. (It will always be on row 4 of 'Sheet 1' tab and row 2 of 'data' tab). I'm trying to work out a way to remove the filter but only if one is set.. can anybody please help!

```
Sheet1.getRange('4:4').activate().getFilter().remove();
data.getRange('2:2').activate().getFilter().remove();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check if [`filter`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getfilter) is not `null`:

```
var filter1 = Sheet1.getRange('4:4').getFilter();
if(filter1){//null is false
  filter1.remove();
}
```